# Spectrum of the inverse operator?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

How can you prove that the spectrum of the inverse of an operator $A^{-1}$ is given by all $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ for all $\lambda \in \sigma(A)\backslash \{0\}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We suppose that $A$ is invertible . By $\rho(T)$ we denote the resolvent set of an operator $T$. Let $ \lambda \ne 0$.

Then:

$$ (*) \quad A^{-1}- \lambda I=A^{-1}(I-\lambda A)=\lambda A^{-1}(\frac{1}{\lambda}I-A).$$

From $(*)$ we see:

$\lambda \in \rho(A^{-1})$  iff $\frac{1}{\lambda} \in \rho(A)$

Comment: Is it possible to construct $A^{-1}$ explicitly?

Comment: Doesn't this post show that $-\lambda A^{-1}$ is the inverse?

Comment: I don't see it. Are you reasoning that since $\lambda A^{-1}(\frac{1}{\lambda}I - A)$ is invertible, then so must $\frac{1}{\lambda}I - A$? This, at least in general unital Banach algebras, is false. (A counterexample are the left- and right-shifts on $\ell^2$: their product is the identity [and hence clearly invertible], yet neither is itself invertible.)