# Compute $\|T^{-1}\|$ and $\|T^{*}+T^{-1}\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normal-operator

Let H be a Hilbert space and assume that $T \in L(H)$ is a normal operator. Suppose that $\sigma(T)=\{a+bi: 1\leq a \leq 2, 1\leq b \leq 2 \}$. How do we compute $\|T^{-1}\|$ and $\|T^{*}+T^{-1}\|$?

Comment: Answer this first :Given the spectrum of a normal operator, how would you deduce its norm? Second, what could be the plausible relationship between the spectra of $T$ and of $T^{-1}$? Taking a guess for starters would help.

Comment: What do you mean by the plausible relationship between the spectra of $T$ and of $T^{-1}$?

Comment: By that , I mean this : given that the spectrum of $T$ is $\sigma(T)$, can you describe the spectrum of $T^{-1}$? That is, can you calculate the spectrum of $T^{-1}$, or at least take a guess of what it could be? If you are still clueless, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038715/spectrum-of-the-inverse-operator. Also keep the hint in the answer below in mind, it is why you require normality above.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Norm of a Normal operator is equal to its spectral radius.